# how to automate adding new data every month

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, automation, power-query

Every month, I add new data from csv file to an excel table. How can that be automated? Looking at the table photo I attached, I have two questions:

1. I want to automatically add new columns with data from the following months both for volume and value. So next to the current E and J columns.
2. I want that the formula from current F and K and L could be updated and be only related to the month that I added.

[image: table example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To many unknowns to provide a definitive answer. You could, for example, combine all of the existing and new csv files; you could use a combination of automate and PQ to load the current table and current month csv; then `Join` them; and I'm sure there are other methods. The simplest to program would probably be a merge of all the individual month csv files from wherever they are located.

Comment: But the problem is that I want to add new data every month. So merging existing CVS files won't work here as the database is ready and need only monthly updates. Or do you mean that each month I merge existing csv files + new ones? What kind of data do you need for a better understanding of my issue?